# Identify a short animated movie about a walking tree in red shoes

Tags: story-identification, animation, movie

I flew with Norwegian airlines and they played some cartoons on board.

Among these there was this funny weird short animated story about a tree who took red shoes of a sleeping man and went on wandering. He always took something making the owner to follow him and this group was getting bigger and bigger.

The art style was kind of simplistic 2D animation, with caricaturous elements. The tree had two eyes aligned vertically rather than horizontally.

As of the origin of the movie, I'm not really sure. By the words in credits I assumed it to be French, but it might as well be Spanish/Catalan, which would make sense since there were some spanish flamenco(?) dancers in the story as well. But I could be wrong with both of the guesses, I don't speak French.

Does anyone know this? What is the name of the short?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is **[One, Two, Tree](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6068004/)**, a French animated short from 2015.

Everything you wrote is there: It's a tree with vertical eyes who steals a sleeping man's red boots and then just keeps taking things from people (among them some flamenco dancers), who then all start chasing it. Here's the trailer:

Comment: Maaaaan. Have you watched all these before (do you even sleep?), or did you find them? (Same ensuing question, do you even sleep?)

Comment: That one I just looked for. ;) And there's no rest for the wicked!

Comment: Nice. I'd be curious to know your successful Google queries, if you're willing to share :)

Comment: Short films are often hard to track down even if I *did* see them, but this one sounded cute so I looked it up and it came up fairly quickly: I searched for a French animated short with 'tree' in the plot on IMDb and the pic in the results was a dead giveaway. :)

Comment: Woah, you, sir, made my day!! I already lost hope I will ever find this! I didn't know about this advanced IMDb search; that seems, indeed, quite useful. I wasn't able to find anything no matter what I tried to put in google :) Thank you!